# Changing font in DT package

Tags: r, dt

easy question I know. Please have mercy on me, I am new to R/R-studio. Looked everywhere for the answer, couldn't find it.

I'm using the DT package to show a simple table, and all the guides show the table being nicely rendered in a Helvetica-like font:

[Image from: https://rstudio.github.io/DT/options.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5nYB.png)

Mine, however, is in a Times New Roman-esque font:
[Not-so-pretty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swNZk.png)

When I use the Viewer pane for anything else it's in the normal Helvetica-like font. So I'm thinking it's something to do with DT's settings? I tried to do an Inspect of the Viewer pane but couldn't find where the font was coded to be Times New Roman...

Here's the code I have for DT so far:

```
table.nice <- datatable(my.df) %>% formatStyle(
  'p-value',
  target= 'row',
  backgroundColor = styleInterval(c(0.05), c('#FFE4E1', 'white')))
table.nice
```

Answer (score 16):

Technically speaking, the DT package doesn't set the default font family. So the browser will use its default font to display the datatable. That's why you find the font displays differently in different browsers.

As to your question, see the following code. It takes advantage of the fact that the `DT` package can pass the JS callbacks to the options of the underlying `datatables` javascript library. See [DT: An R interface to the DataTables library](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/) or [DataTables/Manual/Options](https://datatables.net/manual/options) if you need additional info.

```
library(DT)
datatable(iris, options = list(
  initComplete = JS(
    "function(settings, json) {",
    "$('body').css({'font-family': 'Calibri'});",
    "}"
  )
))
```